# psycopg2 with flask, when to close connection

Tags: flask, psycopg2

I'm trying to build a simple web application that will be querying a postgres db and inserting/deleting data. Since it is a very simple application, I'm not using an ORM layer like sqlalchemy. Instead I'd like to use psycopg directly. Now, I'm wondering, when would be the best time to close cursors and connections? I'm having trouble getting the bigger picture of when the connection is idling with respect to access to the web app.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

maybe the [official documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/database/) can be useful

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
   g.db = connect_db()

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    g.db.close()
```

Comment: Note: this has changed, follow the actual link to see that DB connections should be handled in each context

Comment: As per my understanding, here the connection to the db will be made before processing any request and at the end of each request close the db connection. This looks kind of inefficient to me, since we can use db connection pooling instead of creating and closing the connection for every request and As we know creating a psql db connection is expensive, i.e. it is resource heavy and time-consuming.